# Is there a way to convert an impure pipe to a pure one?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I'm new in Angular 7, but I've been programming AngularJS for a couple of years. My question is based on the fact that when doing an asynchronous task in a pipe (not necessarily an ajax call, it can be another asynchronous task), it must be declared impure.

According to [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes):

> Angular executes an *impure pipe* during every component change detection cycle. An impure pipe is called often, as often as every keystroke or mouse-move.

These are many calls, for example if you use the same pipe in a table of 50 rows or in a list, try placing a `console.log` and you'll see the enormous number of times each pipe is executed again and over again. An example of ajax call in an impure pipe:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {AnyService} from '../services/any.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'anyAjaxCall',
  pure: false
})
export class AnyAjaxCallPipe implements PipeTransform {

  private isDataCached = false;
  private cachedData: string = null;

  constructor(private anyService: AnyService) {
  }

  transform(value: any): string {

    if (!this.isDataCached) {
      this.isDataCached = true;

      this.anyService
        .read(value)
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
          this.cachedData = response.data.name;
        }, (err: any) => {
          this.isDataCached = false;
          console.error(err);
        });
    }

    return this.cachedData;
  }

}
```

Knowing the above, **is it possible to convert a pipe from impure to pure once the asynchronous task has been completed?** I know there is the possibility of saving the result of the asynchronous operation in a variable as a cache and avoiding the execution many times (like the code example above), but I think it would be better in performance to tell Angular that I have already executed my asynchronous task and I don't want to run it again.

I'm not expert in frond-end stuff, so any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, it's not possible to convert it from impure to pure. However, your example is very similar to that given on the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#an-impure-caching-pipe):

```
import { HttpClient }          from '@angular/common/http';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'fetch',
  pure: false
})
export class FetchJsonPipe implements PipeTransform {
  private cachedData: any = null;
  private cachedUrl = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  transform(url: string): any {
    if (url !== this.cachedUrl) {
      this.cachedData = null;
      this.cachedUrl = url;
      this.http.get(url).subscribe(result => this.cachedData = result);
    }

    return this.cachedData;
  }
}
```

For what it's worth, however, depending on your use case, I would move that call into a service (in angular services are singletons) and share the result throughout the application. Later on in the docs when talking about why they no longer have a filter or order by pipe [it does say](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe):

> Any capabilities that you would have put in a pipe and shared across the app can be written in a filtering/sorting service and injected into the component.

Again it depends on your use case, but I hope this helps.